# io.iron.ironmq.HTTPException: Not found (IronMQ JAVA)

Tags: java, ironmq

I'm trying to do a simple aplication in java, that send and recive messages from IronMQ, but when I try to push a message or get a message or clear the queue, java show me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" io.iron.ironmq.HTTPException: Not found
at io.iron.ironmq.Client.singleRequest(Client.java:151)
at io.iron.ironmq.Client.request(Client.java:89)
at io.iron.ironmq.Client.post(Client.java:78)
at io.iron.ironmq.Queue.clear(Queue.java:174)
```

This is the configuration code:

```
public void send_Message() throws IOException{
    Client client = new Client(projectId, token, Cloud.ironAWSUSEast);
    Queue queue = client.queue("Random");
    String body = "Hello, IronMQ!";
    int timeout = 30;
    int delay = 0;
    int expiresIn = 0;
    String messageId = queue.push(body, timeout, delay, expiresIn);
}
```

Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 1):

I see in the error log, that problem is in another piece of code. Concretely, exception says `at io.iron.ironmq.Queue.clear(Queue.java:174)`. Seems, you try to clear queue, which does not exist. It raises the exception, because IronMQ returns HTTP 404 in this case.